# Yii Framework : difference attribute Labels depends on scenario?

Tags: php, yii

I have a User MODEL.

What if a want difference set of attribute Labels, in Case of Login && Change Password ?

[image]

By the way, Is there some thing like this, which I can use it inside the function of Yii's MODEL ?

```
switch($this->scenario ){

    case 'A':
        doThis();
    case 'B':
        doThat();
}
```

Comment: yes you can do that...just remember to set your scenario like...`$model = new ModelName('myScenario');` or use: `$model->setScenario('myScenario');`

Comment: I know how to set, But didn't know how to work with it, expect the 'rules' function in it.

Answer (score 2):

The model inherits the scenario, so you can use something like :

```
   public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'user_id'               => 'User',
            'user_name'             => ($this->scenario =='register'?'Your Preferred User Name':'Your Assigned User Name'),
            'email'                 => 'Email',
            'password'              => 'Password',
            'first_name'            => 'First Name',
            'last_name'             => 'Last Name'
        );
    }
```

Comment: Will fail if there are multiple active scenarios

Comment: Rightly so @JinuJosephDaniel, but multiple scenarios is a special case not part of the original question, In this case, use something like (in_array($this->scenario, array('scenario1, 'scenario2')). The key to the answer is the availability of $this->scenario.

Answer (score 0):

in every model class you have a function `attributeLabels()`, so in class that you want this feature, override it:

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    switch( $this->getScenario() )
    {
        case 'A':
            return $arrayList1;
            break;
        case 'B':
            return $arrayList2;
            break;
        default:
            return $arrayListDefault;
    }
}
```